# javascript sdk and canvas apps

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have a canvas app using the c# facebook graph toolkit, but I make use of the javascript sdk to perform a few functions, most notably facebook dialogs, including feed posts, facebook credits implementation and the requests dialog.  Really all Im using from the javascript sdk is FB.ui and FB.Canvas.  Would the use of the javascript sdk be seen as a facebook connect implementation?

I dont login via the javascript sdk, I merely check for an existing login and then use it to access the javascript functions I require.

My concern is that facebook will consider the app as a connect app and not a canvas app. Does anyone know?